# Java 8 streams transformations and List

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a :

```
Map<String,List<String>> persons
```

And each `String` element in the `List<String>` represents a `Long`

So I want to turn my `Map<String,List<String>>` into a `Map<String,List<Long>>`

The problem is my List are encapsulated into a map. I know with a single List, I can do that :

```
list.stream().map(s -> Long.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But my case is a bit different. Any idea how to proceed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<String, List<Long>> longMap = persons.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> e.getValue().stream().map(s -> Long.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this collect :

```
list.stream().map(s -> Long.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as the `valueMapper` parameter of `toMap()` applied on the stream of the map.

Which would give :

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String,List<String>> persons = ...;
Map<String,List<Long>> personsMapped = 
persons.entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().stream()
                                                      .map(Long::valueOf)
                                                      .collect(toList()))
               );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Map<String,List<String>> persons = ...

 Map<String, List<Long>> result = new HashMap<>();

 persons.forEach((key, value) -> {
        result.put(key, value.stream().map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
 });
```

Comment: why not simply collect toMap?

Comment: @nullpointer because the other answer already does that, I guess

Comment: oh, that ways, I almost thought on the lines of comparing two collectors call versus one type of comparison :) my bad..

Comment: No need for the statement syntax here, i.e. you can remove the curly braces and one semicolon…